# hard drive not detected in windows but in ubuntu it is detected

Tags: windows, ubuntu, hard-drive, diskpart, disk-management

I have a problem with my hard drive . After I reinstalled my windows to Windows10 ,there is no sign of my internal hard drive in windows.*(I have 128G SSD (2x64 GB RAID0) and 1TB SATA hard drive)*
There is no sign of it in **Disk management** , **Diskpart** and **Disk-Drives**(device manager).But **BIOS** detects it. So I tried live ubuntu to check if it's available or not, and it was.I mounted it and it was fine there.
but I have no idea why Windows doesn't diagnose it. Can someone help me with it ?

Comment: Missing drivers for SATA controller? Check _Device Manager_.

Comment: Windows 10?.....

Comment: I would agree with @gronostaj that this is likely a missing driver... You noted with was a RAID0 configuration, so a special driver is likely needed for Windows. Check Device Manager in Windows and look for any question or exclamation marks, anything with a red X or a down arrow (disabled device), or an unknown device and resolve any of those issues first.

Comment: What model is the disk?

Comment: @acejavelin thanks for your response , unfortunately Device Manager seems Ok. There's no problem with any driver.If I understood what you mean

Comment: @harrymc all I know is HDD 1T SATA.

Comment: The model is usually found on the disk as a label.

Comment: is it connected to the motherboard or an add-in card? do you have multiple banks of SATA connectors on the board (perhaps one in Brown, and one that's Grey, or some other color combination)?

Comment: @harrymc the model is ST1000LM024 (Seagate Samsung Spinpoint M8 ST1000LM024 (HN-M101MBB/EX2) 1TB 5400 RPM 8MB Cache SATA 6.0Gb/s 2.5" Internal Notebook Hard Drive Bare Drive )

Comment: @FrankThomas  it is connected to motherboard

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem accidentally . My laptop model is : **SONY PGG-813P** and the model of the hard drive is **ST1000LM024** . I tried every possible solutions that I was capable of doing (as I briefly explained in main topic and comments).I also updated any driver and Windows10 itself.So I thought if the hard drive is available and usable in UBUNTU live (other OS) Maybe my whole system is not supported with win10. So first I tried to install other version of windows like win7 . and surprisingly it worked. I have no idea that what was actually wrong and why win10 was not supported ,but I thought maybe you get the same problem as mine.

Comment: Upgrading from Windows 7 to Windows 10 might (perhaps) keep the disk in working condition.